# Contextual Filter based on internal link

Tags: views

I have two content types: „projects“ and „press articles“. 
The „press article“ has a link internal link field to the related „project“.

How can I create a view, which only displays the „press articles“ which have a link to a certain project?  In the end there should be a link on the „project“ site to it’s related articles, if there a any press article with a link to this project.

It seems that I need to set up a view with a contextual filter, which shows all nodes who have a link to the current node. I have a contextual filter for field_press_related_project:uri, but how do I provide the uri from the current node? „Content ID from url“ does not work.

(It works when i provide a fixed value for the contextual filter field_press_related_project:title)

(I already achieved to have a general press section view, which includes all articles by year.) Now this should be filtered to only the related articles to one project.

thank you very much for any hint.

Comment: What is the field type you're using to link those 2 content types? Just a link or Entity reference? What is your Drupal version? Anyhow, you should be able to filter your results just by adding a filter of that field and check it to be not empty.

Comment: Drupal 8.4.0. There is just a link field from „press articles“ to the „project“, as it needs to link always to one specific project/node. Entity reference would give me the possibilty to link to certain content type, not one specific node.

If I would filter by link field by not empty, every press article would be shown, as all of them have links to certain projects. I need a possibility to only show those, who link to one project/node/url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By having an internal link field type, you're not going to be able to easily pass the right value to your contextual filter as the stored value would be something like `[uri] => entity:node/1`

In order to achieve your goal, I suggest you to replace your "Link" field type with a "Content Reference". In this way you can:
1. Add your field as a contextual filter;
2. Then "Provide default value" as "Content ID from url".

Comment: Yes, that helped, thank you. Just one little question following:
When I set the view path to: „/node/%/related-press“ the id replaces %. 
While when I set the path to „/node/%“ it will rewrite % to the url alias, which I want, but plus the  „/related-press“ in the end?

Comment: I would suspect "/node/%" matches the entity route name this is why it's converted to its alias. I didn't deal with it but maybe you can try creating a route as your pattern.

Comment: I solved this with the subpathauto module.